# Visual Studio Code Java Debugger not Loading

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am new to Visual Studio Code and While trying to run a java any java program they get stuck on loading the debugger extension and I get an error

"Error: there is no registered task type 'Java'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?"

I have ran java files many times before but recently I haven't been having any luck, everything is updated and I have tried reinstalling and restating the extension.

If anyone has any idea it would be very helpful, thanks for reading.

Comment: Make sure you've got the Java Extension Pack installed, Visual Studio Code and Java are updated, JDK is properly configured, JAVA_HOME environment variable is set, and 'java.home' in VS Code settings points to JDK directory. If issues persist, try reinstalling the Java extension and checking for conflicting extensions. For more help, try the official documentation or community forums.

Comment: Do you have the java extension package installed? It will help to follow this starting documentation. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial